# How to solve “complete event for unknown container id”

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

There are some Hadoop error logs like "Container complete event for unknown container id XXX", and the error location is:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.rm.RMContainerAllocator.getResources():622.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It will be easier to help you if you can post a minimal complete example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least give an example of some code that you think is causing the problem.

Comment: There is no explanation of when this error occurs and which process's logs contain these errors?